# Put class on <a> instead li

Tags: menus, walker

I integrate a template into Wordpress theme.  But I have a trouble with the menu.
The menu come with class in `<li>`  like `<li class="nav-link">` if active `<li class="nav-link active">` but I would like to `<a class="nav-link">` if active `<a class="nav-link active">`  I used walker.

this is my menu actually:

```
<nav class="collapse">
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">
<li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-14 nav-link">
    <a href="http://mydom.com/">Accueil</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-85 nav-link">
    <a href="http://mydom.com/a-propos/">A propos</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-97 dropdown nav-link">
    <a href="http://mydom.com/blog/" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Blog<b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-98" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-98 nav-link">
      <a href="http://mydom.com/sample-page/">Sample Page</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-77 current_page_item menu-item-79 nav-link nav-link active">
    <a href="http://mydom.com/contact/">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Now I would like that appear like this:

```
<nav class="collapse">
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">
<li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-14">
    <a href="http://mydom.com/" class="nav-link">Accueil</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-85">
    <a href="http://mydom.com/a-propos/" class="nav-link">A propos</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-97 dropdown">
    <a href="http://mydom.com/blog/" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link">Blog<b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-98" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-98">
      <a href="http://mydom.com/sample-page/" class="nav-link">Sample Page</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-77 current_page_item menu-item-79">
    <a href="http://mydom.com/contact/" class="nav-link active">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I use this class walker and function :

```
class mydom_nav_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {    
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n";
}
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
    if ($args->has_children && $depth > 0) {
        $classes[] = 'dropdown-submenu';
    } else if($args->has_children && $depth === 0) {
        $classes[] = 'dropdown';
    }
    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ($args->has_children)        ? ' data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= ($args->has_children && $depth == 0) ? '<b class="caret"></b></a>' : '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}
function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {

    if ( !$element )
        return;

    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

    //display this element
    if ( is_array( $args[0] ) )
        $args[0]['has_children'] = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
    else if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) 
        $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] ); 
    $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
    call_user_func_array(array($this, 'start_el'), $cb_args);

    $id = $element->$id_field;

    // descend only when the depth is right and there are childrens for this element
    if ( ($max_depth == 0 || $max_depth > $depth+1 ) && isset( $children_elements[$id]) ) {

        foreach( $children_elements[ $id ] as $child ){

            if ( !isset($newlevel) ) {
                $newlevel = true;
                //start the child delimiter
                $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $depth), $args);
                call_user_func_array(array($this, 'start_lvl'), $cb_args);
            }
            $this->display_element( $child, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth + 1, $args, $output );
        }
        unset( $children_elements[ $id ] );
    }

    if ( isset($newlevel) && $newlevel ){
        //end the child delimiter
        $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $depth), $args);
        call_user_func_array(array($this, 'end_lvl'), $cb_args);
    }
    //end this element
    $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
    call_user_func_array(array($this, 'end_el'), $cb_args);
}
}

function webriti_nav_menu_css_class( $classes ) {
    $classes[]  =   'nav-link';
    if ( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes ) OR in_array( 'current-menu-ancestor', $classes ) )
        $classes[]  =   'nav-link active';

    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'webriti_nav_menu_css_class' );
```

In my header I call my menu like this:

```
<nav class="collapse">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
        'container'=>false,
        'walker' => new mydom_nav_walker(),                             
        'items_wrap' => '<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">%3$s</ul>'
    ) ); ?>
</nav>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use your custom Walker class, then there's no point in using filters for adding these classes.

Let's take a look at this part of your code:

```
$class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
$class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

$id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
$id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

$output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

$attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
$attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
$attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
$attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
$attributes .= ($args->has_children)        ? ' data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle"' : '';

$item_output = $args->before;
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
```

In first line you call your filter, and then you use these classes in `<li>` element.

The last line of that fragment is responsible for displaying `<a>` element.

So here's that function with modifications (you don't need to use `nav_menu_css_class` filter anymore):

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
    if ($args->has_children && $depth > 0) {
        $classes[] = 'dropdown-submenu';
    } else if($args->has_children && $depth === 0) {
        $classes[] = 'dropdown';
    }
    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ($args->has_children)        ? ' data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle"' : '';

    $a_classes = array('nav-link');
    if ( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes ) OR in_array( 'current-menu-ancestor', $classes ) ) {
        $a_classes[]  =   'active';
    }
    $attributes .= ( ! empty( $a_classes ) ) ? ' class="' . esc_attr( join( ' ', $a_classes) ) . '"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= ($args->has_children && $depth == 0) ? '<b class="caret"></b></a>' : '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  It works perfectly!  thanks again.